# It is possible to store in memory code from one exercise to another in learnr?

Tags: r, statistics, learnr

I have created a tutorial in `learnr` and I have noticed that for each code chunk that I create, I need to rerun the code from previous chunks if I wish to use the same data.

For instance, if I have something like this :

```
oneway <- aov(data=iris, Petal.Length~Species)
```

which I make in one exercise chunk, and I run:

```
summary(oneway)
```

in the next chunk, it will not recognize "oneway" anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a "feature" of `learnr` such that any exercise can be done at any time without relying on previous steps.

The way around this is by setting up shared `prepare` blocks:

````
```{r prepare-a}
oneway <- aov(data=iris, Petal.Length~Species)
```
```{r a, exercise=TRUE}
oneway
```
````

````
```{r b, exercise=TRUE, exercise.setup = "prepare-a"}
summary(oneway)
```
````

See [Exercise Setup](https://rstudio.github.io/learnr/exercises.html#Exercise_Setup) for more info.